# How can I split a column into multiple rows?

Tags: tables

How can I get [1, 2, 3] in the table below to each appear in a separate row within the same column (with a line between each)? THANKS.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\setcounter{part}{-1}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{Derivation} & \multicolumn{3}{ |c| }{Inflection}\\
\hline
Noun root & -cha, -it.a/u & -ni & -naka/possessive & 1, 2, 3 & -na \\ \hline


\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will it always be that specific column that has to be split? What about the other elements in the row?

Comment: I'd like the other elements in the row just to appear by themselves... though there is one other row that will be split in two...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\setcounter{part}{-1}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\begin{document}
```

[image]

```
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{Derivation} & \multicolumn{3}{ |c| }{Inflection}\\
\hline
Noun root & -cha, -it.a/u & -ni & -naka/possessive & 
\begin{tabular}{c}
  1 \\ \hline
  2 \\ \hline
  3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%1, 2, 3 
& -na \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```